# button s sound makes button press "delay" with [buttonsound prepareToPlay];

Tags: iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer, lag

After the app starts, and I press the start button, it s "lagg" but I used this code into viewdidload and viewdidappear too:

```
gombhang = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button4" ofType:@"mp3"]];

gombha = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:gombhang error:nil];
[gombha prepareToPlay];
gombha.delegate = self;
```

How can I fix this lagg? If I can t fix it apple will reject it?

Comment: I' ve solved my problme: I used this:


`NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button4" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) CFBridgingRetain(soundFileURL), &_MySound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_MySound);`

AVAudioPlayer doens' t work right.

Comment: declared in .h =  SystemSoundID _MySound;

Comment: And another way:

I made an empty/ muted 0.1 sec sound file, and played in viewdidload, and this method loaded the avaudioplayer before I clicked on the start button, so it doesn t lagg anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button4" ofType:@"wav"]; NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile]; AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) CFBridgingRetain(soundFileURL), &_MySound); AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_MySound);
```

And another way: I made an empty/ muted 0.1 sec sound file, and played in viewdidload, and this method loaded the avaudioplayer before I clicked on the start button, so it doesn t lagg anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Audioplayer takes few seconds to load the audio file .

Comment: I waited 15 secs after the start, and it laggs

Comment: I' ve solved my problme: I used this:


`NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button4" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef) CFBridgingRetain(soundFileURL), &_MySound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_MySound);`

AVAudioPlayer doens' t work right.

Comment: And another way:

I made an empty/ muted 0.1 sec sound file, and played in viewdidload, and this method loaded the avaudioplayer before I clicked on the start button, so it doesn t lagg anymore.